# How do I register my iOS app to open zip files from within the mail app in iOS 6+?

Tags: ios, ios6, info-plist

I have an app which I've registered to open zip files by adding the following to the info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>Zip archive</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Alternate</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

In iOS 5, this was enough that the mail app would offer to open zip files in my app.  In iOS 6, it's not; the file doesn't use my app's icon and my app doesn't appear in the list. (It does use the icon in mail compose views, though)

I've tried changing the `CFBundleTypeRole` to Viewer, and the `LSHandlerRank` to Default and even to Owner.  Do I need to add something else to get it to work in iOS 6?  Or have they just removed the ability to open zip files from the mail app?

Comment: I wonder why it was down voted.

Comment: +1 dude, waiting for experts to answer.

Comment: It's not clear from the question - have you added appropriate `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` declaration as described https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW9

Comment: @Mar0ux there shouldn't be any need - com.pkware.zip-archive is one of the builtin UTIs.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1

Answer (score 0):

The following is what works for me in IOS 7.

```
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
  <string>Zip archive</string>
  <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
  <string>Editor</string>
  <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
  <array>
    <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
  </array>
  <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
  <dict>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <string>zip</string>
    <key>public.mime-type</key>
    <string>application/zip</string>
  </dict>
  <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
  <string>Owner</string>
</dict>
```